# Scala: Implicit ordering issue

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalatest

I'm working exercises from the book [Learning Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449367933) and one question asks:

> A popular use for implicit parameters is for a default setting that
>   works most of the time but may be overridden in special cases. Assume
>   you are writing a sorting function that takes lines of text, and the
>   lines may start with a right-aligned number. If you want to sort using
>   the numbers, which may be prefixed by spaces, how would you encode
>   this ability in an implicit parameter? How would you allow users to
>   override this behavior and ignore the numbers for sorting?

My solution:

`def sortLines(l: List[String])(implicit o: Ordering[String]) = l.sorted`

Unit test using Scala Test:

```
"Ch10" should "order lines starting with right-aligned numbers" in {
    val l = List(" 2 a", " 1 b", " 3 c")

    implicit val orderingByNumber: Ordering[String] = Ordering.by(_.trim.split("\\s")(0).toInt)
    val orderingIgnoringNumber: Ordering[String] = Ordering.by(_.trim.split("\\s")(1))

    Ch10.sortLines(l) should contain inOrder(" 1 b", " 2 a", " 3 c")

    Ch10.sortLines(l)(orderingIgnoringNumber) should contain inOrder(" 2 a", " 1 b", " 3 c")
}
```

Problem is the test fails with a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b"`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ordering.by` has the following signature:

```
def by[T, S](f: T => S)(implicit ord: Ordering[S]): Ordering[T]
```

It takes an implicit `Ordering` for the function result type, which in your case is `String`. And the implicit `Ordering[String]` defined at that point is `orderingByNumber`. So what happens is that `orderingIgnoringNumber` cuts the second words from the strings, and tries to order them using `orderingByNumber`, which in turn tries to convert them to `Int`, and throws an exception.

You can try this implementation for `orderingIgnoringNumber`:

```
val orderingIgnoringNumber: Ordering[String] = 
  Ordering.by((_: String).trim.split("\\s")(1))(Ordering.String)
```

This explicitly uses the original `Ordering[String]`.

Comment: Couple questions:
1) Why did you need to explicitly specify `(_: String)`?
2) What's the implicit `Ordering[String]` used for `orderingByNumber`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar 1) No idea. Without it the type checking fails for some reason. 2) The function passed to it produces an `Int`, so it doesn't need an `Ordering[String]`. And the `Ordering[Int]` it uses is the default one provided by Scala.